# Как сохранять настройки выбранные пользователем в телеграм боте на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всем привет, такой вопрос, хочу сделать в боте выбор языка, хочу чтобы при команде start, снизу появлялись две кнопки с языками(рус, eng). При нажатии пользователя на кнопку, я хочу чтоб она исчезала, а выбор пользователя сохранялся в переменную, и исходя из значения переменной информация давалась по выбранному языку. Как это сделать? Библиотека: pyTelegramBotAPI . Желательно без использования БД

Comment: Ну, если вы так не хотите БД, то можете создать текстовый файл и прописать туда выбранный язык. При перезапуске бот будет проверять наличие языка в файле и выбирать его сразу

Answer (score 1):

Рядом с файлом бота(.py) будут находиться текстовые файлы языков. При старте пользователя просит выбрать язык. В соответствии с выбором его user.id будет заноситься в один из текстовых файлов. Например en.txt или ru.txt. При обращении пользователя к боту - скрипт будет проверять наличие этого user id в одном из файлов. Если в файле не окажется user id пользователя - скрипт перейдет к следующему. Если ни в одном из файлов не будет обнаружен user id пользователя - бот предложит пользователю выбрать язык.